# How to push tags with libgit2sharp

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

I need to push tags that exists locally to remote using libgit2sharp. But I could not find how to do it.

I searched a lot in the github repo of libgit2sharp (issues and tests cases) and nothing came up.

[There are some discussions](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/595) about the alternative to `git push --tags` and people saying that this command is just a syntatic sugar to `git push <remote> refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` and that it is exactly what you need to do in libgit2sharp in order to get your tags pushed.

But how can I translate this command

```
git push <remote> refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

Into libgit2sharp code?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 7):

Well, I found the problem in my approach. I was doing something like this:

```
repo.Network.Push(repo.Network.Remotes["origin"], @"refs/tags/*", options);
```

But libgit2sharp do not allow the use of the wildcard (*). Then I did a test removing the wildcard and changing it with the name of one of my tags and it worked.

But I still need send more than one tag to remote, I made a workaround by using a foreach loop, like this:

```
foreach (var tag in repositorio.Tags)
{
    repo.Network.Push(repo.Network.Remotes["origin"], tag.CanonicalName, options);
}
```

Is there another (better or right) way to do it?

Comment: The only way to do it without a loop would be to simulate a `git push origin --tags` command, but I don't know how to do that.